# Analytics on PPA package downloads?

Tags: ppa, launchpad, downloads

Is there some way to get download metrics on PPA packages?  It would be nice to know how many users are using my application from my PPA and what distributions they are using.  If not, any idea of the feasibility of implementing such a feature?  For example, are PPAs mirrored?  I can imagine that that would complicate things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the record, the Launchpad bug URL is:
https://edge.launchpad.net/soyuz/+bug/139855

It looks like the fix is going to be released real soon :)

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the bug link which I subscribed to. Looking forward to this feature :)

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu has a statistics tool called [PopCon](http://popcon.ubuntu.com/) (Ubuntu Popularity Contest). It takes some statistics about packages that are downloaded and even when they are run. You should refer to the [FAQ](http://popcon.ubuntu.com/FAQ) to get more details about this

Answer (score 1):

In addition to popcon, see also http://popcon2.net/ which is an analyzer of those stats. It's not perfect either though and definitely doesn't replace the need for real stats on PPAs.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this has been on the LP roadmap for some time, but apparently hasn't landed yet...  (There is also a LP bug somewhere.)

(And no, PPAs aren't mirrored currently, or at least not outside Launchpad/Canonical where gathering stats would be difficult.)